# error of (Invalid parameters) from stratify method in sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am trying to use stratify method in `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`.
Here is my code:

```
x=df["x"]
y=df["y"]
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split( x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42,statify= y)
```

but I get this error

```
Invalid parameters passed: {'statify': 386 real....Name: y, Length: 527, dtype: object}
```

I look for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842405/parameter-stratify-from-method-train-test-split-scikit-learn), They mention that `stratify splitting` is new in version 0.17 and I have to update my `sklearn`.
I looked for the version of mine. It is `0.20.2`

```
scikit-learn              0.20.2                   pypi_0    pypi
```

So please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

The error you have indicates the parameter `statify` does not exist for this function. No wonder... because there is a typo ;-) it should be `stratify` instead, and this should work with your version of `scikit-learn`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the typo 'statify' , please change it to 'stratify' it will work. Do check this link [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

`