# How to split sparse matrix into train and test sets?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I want to understand how to work with sparse matrices. I have this code to generate multi-label classification data set as a sparse matrix.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(sparse = True, n_labels = 20, return_indicator = 'sparse', allow_unlabeled = False)
```

This code gives me X in the following format:

```
<100x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>' 
with 1797 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

y:

```
<100x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
with 471 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Now I need to split X and y into X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test, so that train set consitutes 70%. How can I do it?

This is what I tried:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.toarray(), y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3)
```

and got the error message:

> TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use
>   X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.

Comment: The error message itself suggests a solution. Run `train_test_split()` function after converting the sparse matrices into dense by calling `X.toarray()` and `y.toarray()`

Comment: @Chinni: Thanks! Can you post the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself seems to suggest the solution. Need to convert both `X` and `y` to dense matrices.

Please do the following,

```py
X = X.toarray()
y = y.toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is the meaning of `stratify=y`?

Comment: Also, for me only this statement works: `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.toarray(), y, test_size=0.3)`

Comment: Could you please check which version of sklearn you are using? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842405/parameter-stratify-from-method-train-test-split-scikit-learn

Comment: I use the version '0.23.0'

Comment: Is there any error that you get when you use `stratify=y`? If so, could you please post it or update your question?

Comment: And I hope you are importing `train_test_split` correctly - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716676/3476748

Comment: Yes, sure, I import it as follows `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`. If I run your code, I get this error `TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.`

Comment: Interesting. Could you please check `type(X)` and `type(y)` after executing `toarray()` on them?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to `stratify=y`. If you look at the documentation for [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), we can see that

`*arrays` :

- Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, **scipy-sparse matrices** or pandas dataframes.

`stratify` :

- **array-like** *(does not mention sparse matrices)*

Now unfortunately, this dataset doesn't work well with `stratify` even if it were cast to a dense array:

```
>>> X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y.toarray(), test_size=0.3)
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```