# Splitting dataset to train and test in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataset whose Label is 0 or 1.

I want to divide my data into a testing and a training data sets. For this, I used the
`train_test_split` method from [scikit-learn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scikit-learn) at first.

But I want to select the test data in such a way that 10% of them are from class 0 and 90% are from class 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you are doing this for a ML project, then most likely you shouldn't be doing this. Data should be split equally among labels.

Comment: Please do some research, read the documentation for `train_test_split` (which answers your question), and share your code. Then people can help you debug it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameter "stratify" from method "train\_test\_split" (scikit Learn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842405/parameter-stratify-from-method-train-test-split-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the official documentation [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split).

You want to specify the response variable with the `stratify` parameter when performing the split.

[Stratification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratification) preserves the ratio of the class variable when the split is performed.

Comment: thanks a lot
But I don't want to keep the ratio of original data classes in the test data.
I want to manually specify the ratio of class 0 and 1 for the test data   @Dan Nagle

Comment: You could simply introduce a dummy field to the data that incorporates the preferred ratio and pass it as the `stratify` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Split your dataset in class 1 and class 0, then split as you want:

```py
df_0 = df.loc[df.class == 0]
df_1 = df.loc[df.class == 1]

test_0, train_0 = train_test_split(df_0, 0.1)
test_1, train_1 = train_test_split(df_1, 0.9)

test = pd.concat((test_0, test_1), 
                    axis = 1, 
                    ignore_index = True).sample(1) # sample(1) is to shuffle the df
train = pd.concat((train_0, train_1), 
                    axis = 1, 
                    ignore_index = True).sample(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own function to do this,
One way to do this is select rows by index and shuffle it after take them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).