# How to sklearn random split test/train set by class and id?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to divide the set into training and test in a 50:50 ratio according to the class 'fruit'. However, so that classes with the same ID go into either the training or test set.

Here is an example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['watermelon', 'watermelon', 'watermelon', 'watermelon', 'watermelon', 
'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 
"lemon", "lemon"], 
'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6 , 7 ,8], 
'value1': random.sample(range(10, 100), 14), 
'value2': random.sample(range(10, 100), 14) })
```

I try:

```
X = df[['value1', 'value2']]
y = df['fruit']
groups = df['ID']
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
train_idx, test_idx = next(gss.split(X, y, groups))
X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[test_idx]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
```

Therefore, for example the watermelon class: three rows will go into the training set (with ID = 1) and two rows will go into the test set (with ID = 2). And same with apple and lemon. However, it divides the set badly that, for example, a class of lemons goes into training or testing and there should be 1 line each in this and that.

Comment: maybe help you, ,stratify=y :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842405/parameter-stratify-from-method-train-test-split-scikit-learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 - Using [StratifiedGroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold)**
According to [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_cv_indices.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-cv-indices-py) this will keep the constraint of the groups while attempting to return stratified folds (stratification might not be exact).

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold

X = df[['value1', 'value2']]
y = df['fruit']
groups = df['ID']

# For a 50/50 split, use n_splits=2
sgkf = StratifiedGroupKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
train_idx, test_idx = next(sgkf.split(X, y, groups))
X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[test_idx]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
```

**Method 2 -  Manual split on each category**
Another solution is to do the split for each fruit category separately and then regroup the elements. This works fine if there are not too many fruit categories, but the total split might not be exactly 50/50 due to odd splits on some fruit categories.

```py
X = df[['value1', 'value2']]
y = df['fruit']
groups = df['ID']
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
train_idx, test_idx = [], []

for fruit in df['fruit'].unique():
    train_idx_fruit, test_idx_fruit = next(gss.split(X[y==fruit], y[y==fruit], groups[y==fruit]))
    train_idx_fruit = X[y==fruit].index[train_idx_fruit] # setting to the initial index
    test_idx_fruit = X[y==fruit].index[test_idx_fruit]

    train_idx += list(train_idx_fruit)
    test_idx += list(test_idx_fruit)

X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[test_idx]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
```

There is probably a cleaner way using groupby instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on more complex cases.

Comment: Depending on what the complexity is, the `StratifiedGroupKFold` method might work better (I have updated the answer).